# Can I find the pitch angle in an android application while taking a picture with the camera?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I'm creating an application in Android Studio in Java.
I want the application to be able to take a picture with the camera, 
is there a way to find the pitch angle of the phone at the moment of the image capture?

Answer (score 0):

`camera2` exposes [`CameraMetadata.LENS_POSE_REFERENCE_GYROSCOPE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#LENS_POSE_REFERENCE_GYROSCOPE),
which might be what you mean by "pitch angle of the phone".

- [`CameraCharacteristics.LENS_POSE_REFERENCE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#LENS_POSE_REFERENCE) should be `GYROSCOPE`.
- [`CameraCharacteristics.LENS_POSE_TRANSLATION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#LENS_POSE_TRANSLATION) has the value.
- There's also [`CameraCharacteristics.LENS_POSE_ROTATION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#LENS_POSE_ROTATION).

Comment: But how can i get the angle of the image and calculate that at the moment the image is taken?

Comment: Those fields just document where the camera lens is relative to the rest of the device, not how the device as a whole is oriented (that is, they say "the camera is 3 cm up from the gyroscope position, and facing away from the user" for example)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to just use the sensor APIs, probably specifically the gravity sensor or the rotation sensor (which looks like it directly gives you the orientation of the device)

There's a short guide [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion#sensors-motion-grav)